# Using OAuth to authenticate Jira REST API through proxy server using Python

Tags: python, curl, proxy, jira, airflow

Having trouble using OAuth creds to connect to the JIRA Server API over a virtual machine because of my company's proxy settings.

I am able to authenticate with OAuth and run my script locally without issue.

I have also tested a version of this script in cURL (below) which works as expected, though it doesn't meet my company's security standards because it's using simple authentication.

JIRA documentation doesn't provide anything helpful and I haven't found any solution on Atlassian Forums or StackOverflow that resolved this particular issue.

Instantiating the JIRA object:

```py
jira_options={'server': 'https://jira.domain.com'}

oauth_dict = {
'access_token': access_token,
'access_token_secret': access_token_secret,
'consumer_key': consumer_key,
'key_cert': key_cert_data
}

jira = JIRA(options=jira_options, oauth=oauth_dict)
```

Here's the functioning CURL w/ simple auth:

```
curl --noproxy “*” -o /usr/local/airflow/data/jira_input.json -D- -u ‘+jira_client_email+‘:’+jira_client_key+' -X GET -H “Content-Type: application/json” “https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=CC&updatedDate=-3d&startAt=0&maxResults=3000”
```

I expect the output to return a JIRA object and allow my program to access JIRA's API.

The actual output is I get is the Error message below:

```
[2019-03-27 15:03:23,907] {bash_operator.py:94} INFO - WARNING:root:HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jira.domain.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /rest/api/2/serverInfo (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f6e45ca5898>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)) while doing GET https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{'params': None, 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'no-check'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your native operating system’s requests go through a windows-based, authenticated proxy, you could used CNTLM on the VM.

Otherwise, try setting Proxy environment variables appropriately on the VM side. These will be used the python requests pip.

Relevant variables

- HTTP_PROXY
- HTTPS_PROXY
- NO_PROXY